# Can a city exploit tiles from two provinces?

Tags: endless-legend

Is it possible to exploit tiles from 2 **different** regions in the same city if both regions are already owned? Is so, what would happen if I lose one in futur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A city is always bound to one region and a region can only have one city. They are in a 1:1 relationship. It is not possible to use tiles of adjacent regions. You have to build a city there to claim them.